# variable css not applying in react js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, ecmascript-6

this is a react app. my css class is not changing even though the state assign to track the boolean value is changing. I've passed my states accordingly for this still not working. here is the github [url](https://github.com/arkapratimsarkar/rjs-assignment)

my app.js file -

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

// Import Styles
import "./styles/App.css";

// Import Components
import Hello from "./components/Hello";
import Rectangle from "./components/Rectangle";
import Button from "./components/Button";

function App() {
  const [colorStatus, setColorStatus] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Hello />
      <Rectangle colorStatus={colorStatus} />
      <Button colorStatus={colorStatus} setColorStatus={setColorStatus} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

button.js -\

```
import React from "react";

const Button = ({ colorStatus, setColorStatus }) => {
  return (
    <div className="button">
      <button className="btn-1" onClick={() => setColorStatus(!colorStatus)}>
        Press
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

rectangle.js -

```
import React from "react";

const Rectangle = ({colorStatus}) => {
  return <div className={`rectangle ${colorStatus ? 'active-rectangle' : '' }`}></div>;
};

export default Rectangle;
```

necessary css -

```
.rectangle {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
  position: fixed;
  top: 30%;
  left: 35%;
}

.active-rectangle {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  background: rgba(0, green, 0, 0.4);
  position: fixed;
  top: 30%;
  left: 35%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.active-rectangle` css-rule needs correction like so :-

```
.active-rectangle {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.4);
  position: fixed;
  top: 30%;
  left: 35%;
}
```

So your state should be getting updated and the `active-rectangle` class is getting applied. Just the `background` property isn't getting applied properly. Rest must still be getting applied.

`background` isn't getting applied properly because you cannot use `green` when a `decimal` value is expected inside `rgba(...)`.

Comment: Yes, I was just writing that I've found the error and got your notification. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Actually your css class is getting changed (according to the url you provided).

Problem seems to be with the usage of `background: rgba(0, green, 0, 0.4)`. Specifically in `rgba(0, green, 0, 0.4)`.

Instead of `green`, it should have been a number from 0 to 255 to denote the green part of the colour.
G of R-G-B-A from `rgba` function you are using

checkout https://cssreference.io/property/background-color/

Answer (score 1):

The problem, as said here before is the background property

Lets refactor the code a bit while we are in it.

```css
.rectangle {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
  position: fixed;
  top: 30%;
  left: 35%;
}

.rectangle.active {
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```
import React from "react";

const Rectangle = ({colorStatus}) => {
  return <div className={`rectangle ${colorStatus ? 'active' : '' }`}></div>;
};

export default Rectangle;
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-galileo-gwzbh?file=/src/components/Rectangle.js